# Mocking Vue RouterView/RouterLink in Vitest (Composition API)

Tags: vue.js, testing, vuejs3, vite, vitest

As per the title, is this possible at all?

I'm trying to test a simple component of a Vue App, which contains a heading and a button that directs user to the next page. I want the test that once the buttons is clicked an event/message is sent to the router, and check that the destination route is correct.

The structure of the app is:

**App.Vue** - the entry component

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
import Wrapper from "@/components/Wrapper.vue";
import Container from "@/components/Container.vue";
import HomeView from "@/views/HomeView.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <Wrapper>
    <Container>
      <RouterView/>
    </Container>
  </Wrapper>
</template>

<style>

  body{
    @apply bg-slate-50 text-slate-800 dark:bg-slate-800 dark:text-slate-50;
  }

</style>
```

**router/index.ts** - Vue Router config file

```js
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router";
import HomeView from "@/views/HomeView.vue";

export enum RouteNames {
    HOME = "home",
    GAME = "game",
}

const routes = [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: RouteNames.HOME,
      component: HomeView,
      alias: "/home"
    },
    {
      path: "/game",
      name: RouteNames.GAME,
      component: () => import("@/views/GameView.vue"),
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
});

export default router;
```

**HomeView.Vue** - the entry view for the RouterView in the App component

```js
<template>
  <Header title="My App"/>
  <ButtonRouterLink :to="RouteNames.GAME" text="Start" class="btn-game"/>
</template>

<script setup>
  import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";
  import ButtonRouterLink from "@/components/ButtonRouterLink.vue";
  import {RouteNames} from "@/router/";
</script>
```

**ButtonRouterLink.vue**

```js
<template>
<RouterLink v-bind:to="{name: to}" class="btn">
  {{ text }}
</RouterLink>
</template>

<script setup>
import { RouterLink } from "vue-router";

const props = defineProps({
  to: String,
  text: String
})
</script>
```

**Considering it's using CompositionAPI, TypeScript, is there any way to mock the router in Vitest tests?**

Here's an example of the test file structure (**HomeView.spec.ts**):

```js
import {shallowMount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import { describe, test, vi, expect } from "vitest";
import { RouteNames } from "@/router";
import HomeView from "../../views/HomeView.vue";

describe("Home", () => {
    test ('navigates to game route', async () => {
        // Check if the button navigates to the game route

        const wrapper = shallowMount(HomeView);

        await wrapper.find('.btn-game').trigger('click');

        expect(MOCK_ROUTER.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: RouteNames.GAME });
    });
});
```

I've tried multiple ways: vi.mock('vue-router'), vi.spyOn(useRoute,'push'), vue-router-mock library and I haven't been able to get the tests to run, always seems like the router just isn't there.

##### Update (15/04/23)

Following @tao 's advice, I realised that testing the click in HomeView is not a very good test (testing libraries rather than my app), so I added a test for **ButtonRouterLink** to see if it renders a Vue RouterLink correctly, using the *to* param:

```js
import {mount, shallowMount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import { describe, test, vi, expect } from "vitest";
import { RouteNames } from "@/router";
import ButtonRouterLink from "../ButtonRouterLink.vue";

vi.mock('vue-router');

describe("ButtonRouterLink", () => {
    test (`correctly transforms 'to' param into a router-link prop`, async () => {
       
        const wrapper = mount(ButtonRouterLink, {
            props: {
                to: RouteNames.GAME
            }
        });

        expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Which renders an empty HTML string `""`

```js
exports[`ButtonRouterLink > correctly transforms 'to' param into a router-link prop 1`] = `""`;
```

accompanied by a rather unhelpful Vue warning (no expected types specified) :

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "to". Expected , got Object  
  at <RouterLink to= { name: 'game' } class="btn btn-blue" > 
  at <ButtonRouterLink to="game" ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
  at <VTUROOT>
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "ariaCurrentValue". Expected , got String with value "page". 
  at <RouterLink to= { name: 'game' } class="btn btn-blue" > 
  at <ButtonRouterLink to="game" ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
  at <VTUROOT>
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <RouterLink to= { name: 'game' } class="btn btn-blue" > 
  at <ButtonRouterLink to="game" ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
  at <VTUROOT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [possible](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/vue-router.html).

There is one important difference between your example and the official one: instead of using `RouterLink` (or a button which uses `router.push`), inside the component being tested, you've placed it in an intermediary component.

How does this change the unit test?

The first problem is you're using [`shallowMount`](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/migration/#shallowmount-and-renderstubdefaultslot), which replaces child components with empty containers. In your case, this means `ButtonRouterLink` no longer contains a `RouterLink` and doesn't do anything with the click. It only receives it.

The options to get past this are:

- a) use `mount` instead of `shallowMount`, making this an integration test rather than a unit one
- b) move the test for this functionality inside a test for `ButtonRouterLink`. Once you test that any `:to` of a ButtonRouterLink is correctly transformed into a `{ name: to }` and passed to a RouterLink, all you need to test is the `:to`'s are passed correctly to `<ButtonRouterLink />` in any component using them.

---

The second problem moving this functionality in its own component creates is a bit more subtle. Normally, I was expecting the following ButtonRouterLink test to have worked:

```js
import { RouterLinkStub } from '@vue/test-utils'

const wrapper = shallowMount(YourComp, {
  stubs: {
    RouterLink: RouterLinkStub
  }
})

expect(wrapper.findComponent(RouterLinkStub).props('to')).toEqual({
  name: RouterNames.GAME
})
```

To my surprise, the test was failing, claiming the received `:to` prop value in the RouterLinkStub was not `{ name: RouterNames.GAME }`, but `'game'`, which is what I was passing to `ButtonRouterLink`. It was like our component never made the conversion from `value` to `{ name: value }`.

Quite strange.
Turns out the problem was that `<RouterLink />` happens to be the root element of our component. Which means the component (`<BottomRouterLink>`) was being replaced in DOM with a `<RouterLinkStub>`, but the value of `:to` was read from the first, not from the latter. In short, the test would have worked if the template was:

```html
  <span>
    <RouterLink ... />
  </span>
```

To get past this, we need to import the actual `RouterLink` component (from `vue-router`) and find ***it*** instead of finding `RouterLinkStub`. Why? `@vue/test-utils` is smart enough to find a stub's component instead of the actual one but, this way, `.findComponent()` would only match the element after the replacement, not when it was still a `ButtonRouterLink` (unprocessed). At that point, `:to`'s value has been parsed into what `RouterLink` is actually receiving.

Full test looks like this:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest'
import ButtonRouterLink from '../src/ButtonRouterLink.vue'
import { RouterLinkStub } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router'

const TEST_STRING = 'this is a test string'

describe('ButtonRouterLink', () => {
  it(`should transform 'to' into '{ name: to }'`, () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ButtonRouterLink, {
      props: {
        to: TEST_STRING
      },
      stubs: {
        RouterLink: RouterLinkStub
      }
    })

    expect(wrapper.findComponent(RouterLink).props('to')).toEqual({
      name: TEST_STRING
    })
  })
})
```

Tricky one.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer, especially the advice with snapshots vs console.log(), it's helpful to understand what's actually being rendered. Also, I see that there isn't much point in testing HomeView button trigger, as I'm not testing any custom behaviours there.
I tried testing ButtonRouterLink as you suggested, I used **mount** on the component, passed a test route name as *to* parameter and took a snapshot to see what renders, but it rendered an empty string "", accompanied by rather unhelpful Vue warning (updated question with the test and the warning message).

Comment: @h0nter, I had to spin a project for a couple of hours until I got to the bottom of it, going through docs and making console bleed to death. See the update to the answer.

Comment: @Pipetus, do you consider i would have been nicer if I didn't give you the advice? Because I believe the opposite. The main difference between our definitions of being nice is that you consider the person's feelings on a very short time scale, whereas I have a longer one in mind. The funny thing is that you're remembered by how people felt in the moment, not by how you make them feel in the future, if you manage to change them for the better. But I guess that's my problem. Thanks for being nice and honest with me. Happy coding!

Comment: That's some really impressive debugging work, thank you so much for your help with this. Now it all makes sense why it wouldn't match the object correctly, so it answers my question. There are two things in your answer, I wanted to check, first, wrapping the ButtonRouterLink in <span> doesn't seem to have any effect as the test errors with: ```Error: Cannot call props on an empty VueWrapper.``` as the ```wrapper.findComponent(RouterLinkStub)``` is a null object. Second, in your final answer, I think we don't need to specify the RouterLink stub, as shallowMount will handle it automatically

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't work when it's not root element, it doesn't make sense. `RouterLinkStub` should ***never*** have a `:to` equal to the string value, it should always be an object, except when it replaces an element with a string `:to`. I might look into it later, but it definitely won't be today.

Comment: Thanks and don't worry, it's not really much of a problem any more since you've answered my question and I have a working test. It's just my curiosity now, why it doesn't work in a consistent way.